# CakeEmail::viewVars - CakePHP

Tags: email, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to set the variable $purchase to use in my email template per the following configuration:

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->emailFormat('html');
$email->template('new_order_email', 'default');
$email->from(array('info@mydomain.com' => 'A Great Site'));
$email->to($this->request->data['email']);
$email->subject('Order details');
$email->viewVars($purchase);
$email->send();
```

But this doesn't work when I attempt to use the $purchase variable in the template. Instead, the email which is sent contains the following error:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: purchase
>   [APP/View/Emails/html/new_order_email.ctp, line 2]

This indicates that $purchase is not available, even though I did set that variable using the CakeEmail:viewVars(); function. Any ideas why I am having this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the quickest and shortest way:

```
$email->viewVars(compact('purchase'));
```

it will pass the var `$purchase` as the same key 'purchase' into the email viewVars and is exactly what you need here.

you can also quickly add more variables this way:

```
$html = 'foo';
$url = '/my/url';

$email->viewVars(compact('purchase', 'html', 'url'));
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
$email->viewVars(array('purchase' => $purchase));
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196759/cakemail-doesnt-recognize-to-and-viewvars-functions/19705245#19705245)

```
$emial->viewVars($valiables);
```

in your email template print this. then you will be able to see all your variables :)

```
var_dump($this->viewVars);
```